# Comparing pairs of fields between files, allowing for offset

Tags: python, unix, awk

I've been trying to solve a rather complex problem (at least it's complex for someone new to this like myself). I have a file ("file1") with hundreds of thousands of rows looking like this (including more fields than shown):

```
1 name1 18 25 A1 ID1
2 name2 28 34 A1 ID1
3 name2 71 123 A2 ID2
4 name3 9 56 A5 ID5
5 name3 9 89 A7 ID7
```

My next file ("file2"), also large, looks like this:

```
1 name1 18 25 52 59 65 78 94 134
2 name1 18 25 52 58
3 name2 28 34 71 123
4 name2 27 35 42 59 61 68 71 125 156 198 206 287
5 name2 28 31 43 56 71 123 158 200
```

Thus, each line of file2 contains "pairs" of values (i.e. fields $3 and $4, fields $5 and $6 etc), some of which are matching the "pairs" in file1 (field $3 and $4) whenever we're on a line starting with the same name in both files. One example of this is the first pair of line 3 in file2 matching the pair in line 2 of file1. Some of the pairs are *almost* matching (e.g. $3 and $4 of row 4 in file2 with line 2 in file1). A pair from file1 can only occur once per line in file2.

What I want to do is, if lines from the two files the same "name" (i.e. same field $2 in this case) to try and match each pair in file2 against the pairs of file1 and if there is a match, output a new file containing the other information from file1 in the format of file2. In other words I want to replace the pairs of numbers in file2 with the "A" and "ID" information from file1 (columns $5 and $6). If no match for the pair in file2 was found in file1, output should be marked, for example as "not found". Note that both first and second value of the pairs should match between the files.

**The twist(s):**

First of all, rows of file2 contain different amount of pairs (a bit over a hundred columns).

Secondly, *I want to accept "fuzzy" matches*. What I mean by this is to accept any values from file2 being, say, +/- 5 from the actual values in file1 (i.e. (value in file1)-5 < (value in file2) < (value in file1)+5).

The values in the input files are in reality much larger than shown in the examples. All in all the output in this case would look something like this ("file3"):

```
1 name1 A1 ID1 not found not found not found
2 name1 A1 ID1 not found
3 name2 A1 ID1 A2 ID2
4 name2 A1 ID1 not found not found A2 ID2 not found not found
5 name2 A1 ID not found A2 ID2 not found
```

I have thus far, unsuccessfully, been barking up the awk tree in my quest for a solution.

I'm quite literally stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    a[$2][$3][$4][5] = $5
    a[$2][$3][$4][6] = $6
    next
}
$2 in a {
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        hit = 0
        for (key3 in a[$2]) {
            if ( abs($i - key3) < 5 ) {
                for (key4 in a[$2][key3]) {
                    if ( abs($(i+1) - key4) < 5 ) {
                        hit = 1
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (hit) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        $i     = (hit ? a[$2][key3][key4][5] : "not")
        $(i+1) = (hit ? a[$2][key3][key4][6] : "found")
    }
}
{ print }
function abs(v) { return (v<0 ? -v : v) }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
1 name1 A1 ID1 not found not found not found
2 name1 A1 ID1 not found
3 name2 A1 ID1 A2 ID2
4 name2 A1 ID1 not found not found A2 ID2 not found not found
5 name2 A1 ID1 not found A2 ID2 not found
```

Comment: Seems to be working correctly, thank you very much! Also, I edited my post; a pair from file1 can only occur once per line in file2.